# proper parts of speech and analysis of structure

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, parts-of-speech

Find the wrong one(S)

> 1. I saw injustice happen.
> 2. I saw injustice happening.
> 3. I saw injustice happened.

This is from a grammar competition. Now from my little knowledge. I can only break it down as, I - subject, saw- verb, injustice-object. I am not sure about which parts of speech the word 'happen' is used in different sentences. My guess is in 2 it is a participle but I have no solid basis of saying it. It's just have +ing form and to me, it looks like it is qualifying the obj - injustice in a sense. Hence, participle. But again, I may be wrong about my analysis. I have no idea about the other sentences.

Comment: They all look grammatical to me. (The third one is simply *I saw **that** injustice happened*, without *that*, which is a stylistic choice.)

Comment: Yes the answer key is all are okay. What I am not getting the structure. I mean the different use of happen as different parts of speech in different sentences. If you can break it to me in the answer that would be great.

Comment: Is it just the use of *injustice* and *happen* that are throwing you off? What if the were following were the three sentences? (1) I saw him attack. (2) I saw him attacking. (3) I saw him attacked. Would you still be confused about the structure? Because it's almost exactly the same with those sentences.

Comment: 1st confusion attack in 1st) example of your's is noun. But to my knowledge happen is verb or adverb.

Comment: 2nd) if your example as same as mine do you mean in 2)) I saw him attacking.  attacking is participle and 3) I saw him attacked, attacked is past participle?